# gnuplot call command not supporting arrows and labels

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to create what amounts to a subroutine in gnuplot using the "call" command.

I have a file, label.gp containing

```
set arrow 1 from first ARGV[1], first 110 \
            to first ARGV[1], first 114 \
               dt 5 lc rgb ARGV[3] nohead
set arrow 2 from first ARGV[1], first 112 \
            length character -4 angle 0 \
            backhead lc rgb ARGV[3]
set label 1 at first ARGV[1], first 112 right tc rgb ARGV[3] \
          offset character -4.5, character 0.0 ARGV[2]

print ARGV[1]
print ARGV[2]
print ARGV[3]
```

that's supposed to put a labelled arrow on the graph.

Then in my main gnuplot file, preceded by a lot of setup, I have

```
call 'label.gp' "2021-09-01-00-00" "Event" "blue"
call 'label.gp' "2021-09-02-00-00" "Another Event" "red"
plot [:] [40:130]  .......
```

That draws the graph and is supposed to draw the arrows and labels.  It doesn't.  The print commands in label.gp do the right thing, and the plot is drawn, but the labels aren't.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is a bug that occurs when array elements are given as position parameters for "set arrow" and "set label".

This can be easily demonstrated with the following script.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"

T1 = "2021-09-01-00-00"
T2 = "2021-09-02-00-00"

array T[2] = [T1, T2]

set arrow 1 from "2021-09-01-00-00", 0 to "2021-09-02-00-00", 0
set arrow 2 from T1, 0 to T2, 0
set arrow 3 from T[1], 0 to T[2], 0

show arrow 1
show arrow 2
show arrow 3
```

This script will produce the output like this using gnuplot 5.4.

```
    arrow 1, head nofilled back linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
      from ("2021-09-01-00-00", 0.00000, 0.00000) to ("2021-09-02-00-00", 0.00000, 0.00000)


    arrow 2, head nofilled back linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
      from ("2021-09-01-00-00", 0.00000, 0.00000) to ("2021-09-02-00-00", 0.00000, 0.00000)


    arrow 3, head nofilled back linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
      from ("1970-01-01-00-33", 0.00000, 0.00000) to ("1970-01-01-00-33", 0.00000, 0.00000)
```

Only "arrow 3", which uses array elements as position parameters, shows unintended behavior.

#### Workaround 1

Use ARG1 instead of ARGV[1].

```
set arrow 1 from first ARG1, first 110 \
            to first ARG1, first 114 \
               dt 5 lc rgb ARGV[3] nohead

...
```

#### Workaround 2

Assign ARGV[1] to a user defined variable and use that variable as position parameter.

```
xpos = ARGV[1]
set arrow 1 from first xpos, first 110 \
            to first xpos, first 114 \
               dt 5 lc rgb ARGV[3] nohead
...
```

Comment: Workaroud 2 did it.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are providing the x coordinates for your labels and arrows as dates, but you have not shown what commands you used to define the date format and x axis range.   I suspect the problem is that the strings you show do not match the time format that is in effect at the time the "set label ..." commands are executed.

Try preceding the `call` commands with something like:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"
set xrange [ "2021-01-00-00" : "2022-01-00-00" ]
call ...
call ...
```